# Upgrading neo4j minor version

Tags: neo4j

I have recently upgraded Neo4j from version 3.5 to version 4. The question is, in order to update Neo4j to the latest maintenance release, is it necessary to do all steps outlined in this link https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/, or it will be correct and sufficient to download the latest version and copy the **data** directory to the new Neo4j installation ?

The steps documented in the link has been done when moved from 3.5 to 4.0.3. I am going to update it from version 4.0.3 to version 4.0.4.

Comment: You should always follow the documented upgrade instructions.

Comment: Are there any in particular you're concerned about or feel might be unnecessary?

Comment: @Aaron, the majority of the steps are to ensure a safe migration from a previous store version to the next.

Rephrasing my question, Could minor neo4j versions introduce changes to the database store ?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice video from David Allen about the upgrade process

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcaJ-aVLzr4